# first time using python to connect with sqlite3 getting error

Tags: python, sqlite

I have installed Pyhton 3.5.1 version,

tried to connect sqlite to it with following code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
```

It worked well for first time so I left it as it was. Came back to computer and I tried to use the same code again

However I am receiving this message now all the sudden using the same code:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file**

I find it very strange, because I haven't done anything special afterwards when using code for first time. I am new to Python and I have absolutley no idea why I get this. Any help would be more then welcome.

Comment: Have you made sure that the file is really there?

Comment: well it shouldn't matter, because sqlite3 either creates new database or open existing one

Comment: Directory? Writable?

Comment: using command prompt

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you did not close the database connection properly in your program, when accessing the database the first time. Try to close and exit your program and your IDE and start again.

After that, make sure that you end the connection properly, with a command like `conn.close()`.